# Is Ember RESTAdapter namespace inheritable?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Suppose we have the following code:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: '/webapp_name'
    host: 'http://localhost:8080'
});

App.PersonAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: '/foo/bar'
});
```

So, is the model `App.Person` targeting at `http://localhost:8080/webapp_name/foo/bar/person` or `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar/person`?

Comment: Try inheriting your `PersonAdapter` from `App.ApplicationAdapter` instead of `DS.RESTAdapter`. Then it will "target" `http://localhost:8000/foo/bar/persons`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an Adapter is just an Ember Object and can be extended, but your example is not inheriting the `PersonAdapter` from the `ApplicationAdapter`.

You need `App.PersonAdapter` to extend from `App.ApplicationAdapter` if you wish to inherit the `host` property from `App.ApplicationAdapter`.

```
App.PersonAdapter = App.ApplicationAdapter.extend({
    namespace: '/foo/bar'
});
```

The above will now have the `host` property inherited from ApplicationAdapter, but namespace will be overridden with the result being `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar/xxx`